# How can one shutdown a PC using the keyboard?

Tags: shutdown, 14.10

I would like to find a way to speed the shutting down process up by using shortcut keys.

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 - Utopic Unicorn on a Compaq HP, but I am not able to do that by following the methods used for the previous Ubuntu versions.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can add: Shut Down;Reboot;Suspend;Hibernate;Log Out and Lock Screen functions to the dash via the following commands:        sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao      and:      sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install power-commands

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do

```
> sudo init 0
```

to shutdown your computer from the terminal or

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

to reboot it. Besides you can do `man shutdown` which will give you more detailed information about the shutdown command.

Comment: How do you open a terminal with the keyboard?

Comment: usually `Ctrl+Alt+T`

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+F1` also generally works, IIRC (it changes from showing the desktop environment to showing a virtual terminal)

Comment: @cpast Don't forget to mention that if you want to go back to the DE, use ctrl+alt+F7

Comment: @Kroltan If you're doing this to shut the computer down, that's not such an issue.

Comment: @cpast In most cases, that's true. But at least I often remember doing something before shutting down the PC, and knowing how to go back might be very useful.

Answer (score 9):

The quickest way to PROPERLY shut down any PC running Ubuntu Linux that I know of regards something that can only be properly described as a sort-of keyboard shortcut when using a laptop.

You merely TAP (do not hold down) the power button.  This causes a shutdown dialogue to appear in which the highlighted option is SHUT DOWN, so if you then press the ENTER key the computer will begin the orderly shutdown process, and will typically shut down in under 5 seconds.

So from the top, TAP power button and press enter.  It shuts down so fast your windows friends will assume you merely closed the lid.

Comment: in case you are wondering, this is how I turn off ALL my ubuntu computers.  Even desktops.  I tap the power button on the front.  I'm in the process of building a high end desktop for my sister OUT OF WOOD.  The design is a little abstract.  I'm going to give it a remote power button which will reside near her keyboard but shrouded so that it cannot be pressed by accident.

Comment: I don't even see that shutdown dialog, probably because I've disabled it in dconf-editor, so it's definitely the quickest way available for me.

Comment: wait... what?  you DISABLED a shutdown dialogue?   No doubt to make shutting down faster.  I can understand why you might do that if you believed that going to the icon in the upper right corner was sufficiently annoying without having to press enter on a shutdown dialogue was too much additional work but really.  I think the combination of tapping your power button and a disabled shutdown dialogue is going to bite you later.  Please consider re-enabling that confirmation screen.

Comment: I can't think of a scenario where I would miss that dialog, as I have ctrl+alt+backspace to logout and the session menu item to restart.

Comment: I don't know whether to be annoyed or amused that my answer got four upvotes but the chosen answer, not mine, received only two.  I'm guessing this means that the one who asked the question was not satisfied with my solution but at least four people particularly liked it.

Answer (score 4):

- Hit the power button.
- Use arrow key to go to "shutdown".
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It works with all Ubuntu versions, and it is (to me) the quickest way to shutdown a machine.

Comment: Esc doesn't bring anything up for me in xubuntu 14.04

Comment: Same here, a no-go in xfce. Why would Unity make a single ESC key the "shutdown" shortcut? Common to stop webpages from loading with esc key.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a `sudo shutdown -h now` in tty ahead of time, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type in your password and don't press enter. When you want to shut down, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can also restart in tty by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> without a sudo, but then you need to shut down before it restarts.

Comment: Well played, well played...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type: `sudo init 0`

Comment: "Need to be root" for this command, which is not a very quick way ;-)

Comment: `sudo halt` is an alternative with less keystrokes

Comment: @Maerlyn ...not counting the password

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the terminal and power button path, there is one more way using regular keyboard shortcuts.

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f10</kbd> to take the focus to top bar.
2. Now use the arrow key to move to power menu on the extreme right.
3. Use arrow key again to select `shutdown`.
4. Choose restart or shutdown again with arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to press Power button on your keyboard.

Just go to Power Option and set Power key to shutdown your pc.

Answer (score -1):

**If your GUI ubuntu desktop is not freezed**, open a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut and do the following:

To shutdown now :

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

To restart now :

```
sudo shutdown -P -r now
```

To shutdown after (say) 20 minutes :

```
sudo shutdown -P 20
```

Similarly, for restart also replace `now` by `20`.

(**To stop timed execution:** Say after 15 minutes you decide not needed to shutdown/restart then go to the terminal window in which you executed the command and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.)

---

**If your GUI ubuntu desktop is freezed**, go to commandline ubuntu desktop by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>(Here in place of <kbd>F1</kbd>, the keys <kbd>F1</kbd>to <kbd>F6</kbd> are applicable ; also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> will give you the GUI desktop back). Now in commandline ubuntu enter your login username and password. After successful login execute the same commands described above for shutdown (or restart).